# What does the HP/kW power rating on the specification sticker of a pump mean?

Tags: power, motor, efficiency, fluid-pump

Pumps have power given as kW/HP on the specification sticker and also efficiency is mentioned on them. Is this power the electrical input power or mechanical output power? For example in this case is the electrical power used by the pump 3 HP/2.2 kW or 3HP/2.2kW / (0.4) ? Here 0.4 is the efficiency of the pump given in this sticker[image]

Comment: I assume you know that 3HP is the same as 2.2 kW, but that's not completely clear in your question

Comment: @ChrisH -- so are you saying that 2.2/3.0 is expressing the same physical quantity with two different units, and not giving a ratio? I.e., it could have been written in two separate fields: kW 2.2 and HP 3.0?

Comment: @PeteBecker exactly. 1Hp ([horsepower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower) is defined as 0.746 kW (similar but not identical values are used in other fields).  HP is the preferred unit in the US, kW in other countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3-phase 415V, 4.7A is about 3kVA, so the whole thing could not be above 3kW electrical.

(3-phase 415V electrical grid is in fact 3 x 230V and 415V is between phases, and you should multiply 3 x 230V x 4.7A in order to get VA power)

The plate says 2.2kW, so the power factor is ~0.73 - pretty much normal for this type of appliance.

The efficiency is the ratio between the pumping power and the electrical power. Your pumping power is 2.2kW * 0.4 = 880W

If you pump water at 26.7m head, the water will flow at about 3.3 liter per second to make these 880W.

The plate capacity range says 2.5-4.5 liter per second. It relates to pumping with different water head.

Everything fits, doesn't it?

Edit: some numbers wrong, fixing

Edit2:

HP (horsepower) in this context is equal to 0.735kW, so 2.2kW are 3.0HP within the 2-digit accuracy